# Есть ли бесплатные аналоги Google maps для Андроид?

Tags: android, google-maps

Хочу встроить карты в свое Android приложения, но Google maps платный. Есть ли бесплатные аналоги?

Comment: а что по этому поводу говорит товарищ Гугл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогов достаточно много. [Вот](https://locationiq.com/) к примеру аналог которые дает 10к обращений бесплатно а дальше нужно платить. [Вот](https://openlayers.org/) еще один пример где все бесплатно. Вот [статья_1](https://www.maketecheasier.com/google-map-alternatives/), [статья_2](https://nordicapis.com/5-powerful-alternatives-to-google-maps-api/) и [статья_3](https://geoawesomeness.com/google-maps-api-alternatives-best-cheap-affordable/) по вашему вопросу. Надеюсь вы найдете то что вам подойдет для ваших задач